# Merging code with dependencies?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, underscore.js

This might be quite simple, but I must say I'm a bit confused on this topic.

I'm writing code based on two popular libraries:

- jQuery
- underscore.js

I am just wondering **what would be the best way to isolate the code and prevent conflicts and how to merge it with its dependencies?**

By merging I mean putting them within the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily place the two of them in the same file, because the only things they turn global are `window._`, `window.$` and `window.jQuery`. The other variables and functions are wrapped in a local scope, so there will be no conflict.

---

**Edit**: Your own code could be put in the same file too. And if you prefer to remove the globals, both jQuery and Underscore have a no-conflict method, which replaces the globals with their old values (often `undefined`). You could wrap your code in your own local scope and there'll be no problems anymore:

```
// jQuery and Underscore source here

// You code here, wrapped in a self-executing function:

(function($, _){

  // here you can add your code:
  $('#test').text('jQuery works');

  _(3).times(function(){
    alert('Underscore works' );
  });

})(jQuery.noConflict(true), _.noConflict());

// no jQuery nor Underscore here:

alert(typeof jQuery, typeof $, typeof _);
```

This looks quite tricky, but let me explain it very quickly. You can execute a function immediatly after defining it, like this:

```
(function(){
  alert('I am being executed');
})();  // <-- basically how you call a function normally: func();
```

And you can pass arguments in it:

```
(function(a){
  alert(a);
})('test');
```

Both `$.noConflict()` and `_.noConflict()` remove the global variables and return a reference to the jQuery and Underscore variable. So you can pass these in the self-executing function as arguments and everybody's happy (:

Comment: what about my own code? Pasting it within the same file won't create any problems? Also I would like to avoid $ and _ being global. Thanks for your help!

Comment: oh wow! Thank you very much, very informative! Thanks for your Xmas present :) Merry Christmas